# php function work on localhost but not working on server

Tags: php

php function work on localhost but not working on server,
function:

```
  function camelCase($str, array $noStrip = []){
    // non-alpha and non-numeric characters become spaces
    $str = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9' . implode("", $noStrip) . ']+/i', ' ', $str);
    $str = trim($str);
    // uppercase the first character of each word
    $str = ucwords($str);
    $str = str_replace(" ", "", $str);
    $str = lcfirst($str);

    return $str;
}
```

I recieve this **error**:

[image]

please help

Comment: PHP version on server is 5.3?

Comment: Change `[]` to `array()`.

Comment: You use the array notation for PHP 5.5 and higher. Change your server to 5.5 or change your notation to array.

Comment: Check the server logs for the error.  There should be something in the webserver log and perhaps something in the PHP log as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58677100/12314377

Comment: If anyone could help regarding the below question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/58677100/12314377

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried accessing documents on the server e.g. a simple html document? 
If this works check your php version with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` on the server and localhost. Your're useing notation of PHP 5.5 make sure this runs on the server!