# Payment form action work on localhost, but is not working on server

Tags: codeigniter

The form action works fine on localhost, however it doesn't work on server.

When I click the button pay now on localhost it directs me to the correct URL. But on server it directs me to `mywebsite.com/Gateways/Migs/hitmigs`.

**Here is the code in migs:-**

```
$form = '<form action="'.base_url('Gateways/Migs/hitmigs').'" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<input type="hidden" name="Title" value = "Migs Transaction - PHPTravels">
<input type="hidden" name="virtualPaymentClientURL" size="65" 
value="https://migs.mastercard.com.au/vpcpay" maxlength="250"/>
<input type="hidden" name="vpc_Version" value="1" size="20" maxlength="8"/>
<input type="hidden" name="vpc_Command" value="pay" size="20" maxlength="16"/>
```

**migs in controller folder**

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit ('No direct script access allowed');

class Migs extends MX_Controller{

    public function hitmigs(){      
        $redirect_url = "";
        require_once(__DIR__."/../migs/PaymentCodesHelper.php");
        include_once(__DIR__."/../migs/VPCPaymentConnection.php");
        include_once(__DIR__."/../migs/PHP_VPC_3Party_Order_DO.php");
        redirect($redirect_url);
```

I have tried to change PHP versions to 5.5 and 5.6 and asked hosting company to change `[]` to `array()`

Comment: If I understand correctly, your form submits to your `hitmigs()` Controller method, which includes 3 mystery files and then does a redirect.  If that redirect does not work, then either something is generating an error, or `$redirect_url` is not being set correctly.  So, what do your server logs say?  Have you added some debugging in those mystery files, are they all being included and processed correctly?

Comment: It has been resolved
It was case sensitive
$form = '<form action="'.base_url('gateways/Migs/hitmigs').'" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">

Comment: Great you solved it. For such errors, SO recommends closing the question, maybe you could do that.  From the close dialog: *It's caused by a typo or problem that can no longer be reproduced. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers.*